# checking on success of write.csv in R

Tags: r

In R, how do I verify that `write.csv(my.data.frame, file='test.csv')` was successful without re-reading it in again?  It doesn't seem to return anything.  I was thinking of doing a `file.exists('test.csv')` and then grabbing a timestamp before and after the `write.csv()` and checking that the timestamp on the file is between the two?  Any suggestions?

Comment: You could read the first few lines with `readLines` and see if column names match (or have a more complicated test).

Comment: Are you more interested in if the file was written (in which case `file.exists` on its own will work)? Or do you want to know if it was written correctly?

Comment: Good point @sebastian-c - really I suppose I just want to give feedback to the user if they have passed down a bad file location, or there was no space, or no permissions, or something like that.  So Ali's answer below looks like it is a strong contender.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may use the function `try()`:

```
res <- try(write.csv(1:100, "SOME GOOD PATH/temp.csv"))
is.null(res)
# [1] TRUE
res <- try(write.csv(1:100, "SOME BAD PATH/temp.csv"))
is.null(res)
# [1] FALSE
class(res)
# [1] "try-error"
```